# How decode random value from array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, random, decode

I have array (slovoArray) and I am using arc4random to obtain random values. Now I do not know how to get out of numbers (random number is for example 1340), the correct values (name and definition) and then fill them in the two labels. Probably I need a random number obtained from the array somehow decode, but do not know how. Pls help.

**This is code in my class RandomViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.slovoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   SlovaParser *menuParser = [[SlovaParser alloc] initWithArray51:self.slovoArray];
    [menuParser parseXMLFile];

   NSLog(@"Number of items in my array is: %lu", [self.slovoArray count]);

   NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [self.slovoArray count];

   NSLog(@"Random is: %lu", randomIndex);

   self.definiceText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.slovoArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
}
```

**Solved!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *encoded_string = @"Ã¼";
const char *ch = [encoded_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *decode_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",decode_String)
```